# Can't connect pgadmin to postgresql running inside docker container initialized from docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I can't access postgresql server from outside the container, although i'm able to do so from inside the container.

I have defined in my compose.yaml file the following variables:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgredb
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "PostGres2023!"
      POSTGRES_DB: potato
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --auth=scram-sha-256
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

I included POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --auth=scram-sha-256 after realizing that I was able to log in to the server without a password from inside the container.

```
C:\Users\lucab>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
db276a10e549   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgredb

C:\Users\lucab>docker exec -it db276a10e549 bash
root@db276a10e549:/# psql -h localhost -U postgres
psql (16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1))
Type "help" for help.
```

Meanwhile i tried logging from pgadmin in my local machine, which yields an annoying password error:

[PG-ADMIN SERVER REGISTER PROMPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk8UT.png)

after the "POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --auth=scram-sha-256" line I was asked the password from the inside the container and managed to log in just fine with the defined value on the compose.yaml file (**Note the line "Password for user postgres:"**):

```
C:\Users\lucab>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
5566cb874560   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 minutes ago   Up 20 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   postgredb

C:\Users\lucab>docker exec -it 5566cb874560 bash
root@5566cb874560:/# psql -h localhost -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I thought this would have fixed my problem since the pgadmins error might`ve been coming from the server not needing a password and pgadmin not connecting unless a password was provided. clearly this is not the case. With any password value i inputed the error in pgadmin was the same. If i leave the password prompt blank it returns:

[PG-ADMIN SERVER REGISTER PROMPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSCNl.png)

for further debug, here are the container logs:

```
2023-10-29 18:56:53 The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2023-10-29 18:56:53 This user must also own the server process.
2023-10-29 18:56:53 
2023-10-29 18:56:53 The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2023-10-29 18:56:53 The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2023-10-29 18:56:53 The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2023-10-29 18:56:53 
2023-10-29 18:56:53 Data page checksums are disabled.
2023-10-29 18:56:53 
2023-10-29 18:56:53 fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
2023-10-29 18:56:53 creating subdirectories ... ok
2023-10-29 18:56:53 selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2023-10-29 18:56:53 selecting default max_connections ... 100
2023-10-29 18:56:53 selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
2023-10-29 18:56:53 selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
2023-10-29 18:56:53 creating configuration files ... ok
2023-10-29 18:56:53 running bootstrap script ... ok
2023-10-29 18:56:53 performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
2023-10-29 18:56:54 syncing data to disk ... ok
2023-10-29 18:56:54 
2023-10-29 18:56:54 Success. You can now start the database server using:
2023-10-29 18:56:54 
2023-10-29 18:56:54     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
2023-10-29 18:56:54 
2023-10-29 18:56:54 waiting for server to start....2023-10-29 21:56:54.105 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.108 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.115 UTC [51] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-10-29 21:56:53 UTC
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.119 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-10-29 18:56:54  done
2023-10-29 18:56:54 server started
2023-10-29 18:56:54 CREATE DATABASE
2023-10-29 18:56:54 
2023-10-29 18:56:54 
2023-10-29 18:56:54 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
2023-10-29 18:56:54 
2023-10-29 18:56:54 waiting for server to shut down....2023-10-29 21:56:54.307 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.310 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.311 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 54) exited with exit code 1
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.311 UTC [49] LOG:  shutting down
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.314 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.388 UTC [49] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 923 buffers (5.6%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.014 s, sync=0.054 s, total=0.077 s; sync files=301, longest=0.015 s, average=0.001 s; distance=4257 kB, estimate=4257 kB; lsn=0/19130D0, redo lsn=0/19130D0
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.393 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-10-29 18:56:54  done
2023-10-29 18:56:54 server stopped
2023-10-29 18:56:54 
2023-10-29 18:56:54 PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
2023-10-29 18:56:54 
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.428 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.428 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.428 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.433 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.439 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-10-29 21:56:54 UTC
2023-10-29 18:56:54 2023-10-29 21:56:54.444 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-10-29 18:57:46 2023-10-29 21:57:46.709 UTC [77] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2023-10-29 18:57:46 2023-10-29 21:57:46.709 UTC [77] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 115: "host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256"
2023-10-29 18:58:01 2023-10-29 21:58:01.424 UTC [81] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2023-10-29 18:58:01 2023-10-29 21:58:01.424 UTC [81] DETAIL:  Connection matched file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf" line 115: "host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256"
2023-10-29 19:01:54 2023-10-29 22:01:54.538 UTC [62] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2023-10-29 19:01:58 2023-10-29 22:01:58.789 UTC [62] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 45 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.217 s, sync=0.022 s, total=4.251 s; sync files=12, longest=0.008 s, average=0.002 s; distance=261 kB, estimate=261 kB; lsn=0/1954540, redo lsn=0/1954508
```

Comment: When I run your docker-compose file, everything works for me logging in through pgAdmin, or from the command line on the host, or through docker exec.  However, I get v15.1, not v16.0.  I'm not much of a docker user, any idea why we both don't get the same version when running the same file?

Comment: Perhaps when you run the docker compose it is using the version 15.1 of postgres because you already have an image with that version downloaded on docker images. Since I didn't have any image, it was pulling the latest version. When you executed docker compose did it say it was pulling postgres?

Comment: Ah, I thought it would automatically detect the newer available image and download it. After deleting all images (and reinstalling docker desktop, which somehow got screwed up) I now get 16.0, and it works.  I don't see any likely candidates for problem which would lead to that error message.  I guess I would change the password so it didn't have an exclamation point in it and see if that worked  (but I used the same password you did, so I don't understand why that would be a problem for you but not me)

Comment: Are you running docker from a linux OS? I forgot to mention that i'm on windows 11 OS. I`ve read here: https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/ that host networking only functions on linux. Maybe that means that port mapping to local host also should not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres by default is configured to listen to port 5432. This means that in port configuration, if you want to connect your local machine to the postgres docker container, the port of the postgres docker container that will be accessed by your local computer via localhost must be 5432. This holds true, unless port configuration within the docker postgres is changed. The available port in your local machine can be any port. This lead me to change the port line in compose.yaml:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgredb
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "PostGres2023!"
      POSTGRES_DB: potato
    ports:
      - 8039:5432
```

which lead to a successful connection within psql:

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]: 8039
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
psql (16.0)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
     8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
     page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but since your log file showed failed connection attempts, people must have been able to get through so I rejected that theory.  Maybe those failed attempts came from when you did `docker exec`?  On Linux, when you try to set up a mapping from a host port when that port is already in use, docker will refuse to start up the container.  But in windows in this circumstance, it just ignores the attempted mapping and proceeds anyway.  Worse yet, `docker ps` actually show the mapping being in effect when it is not.